# Add some header dependencies of source files to solution explorer for cmake target

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

Suppose I have `a.cpp` as a source and I add it to a cmake target:

```
add_executable(MY_TARG a.cpp)
```

If `a.cpp` includes `a.h` it will be added as a dependency for the target and when I change the header, everything will get rebuilt properly, but `a.h` won't show up in the list of sources for my project (in visual studio for instance).

Is there a way to add it there?
And can I distinguish between system headers (like `<vector>`) and headers from a folder from the same directory structure? I might wish to add only headers included with quotes and not with brackets (`"header.h"` and not `<header.h>`)

I am looking for something automatic - I already have a lot of CMakeLists.txt files with only .cpp files listed there and going through all of them seems impractical.

Comment: I've edited my answer to list a possible way of automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple - if you want a file to be listed as part of a project in an IDE, list it as part of the target in CMake:

```
add_executable(MY_TARG a.cpp a.h)
```

CMake knows enough to recognize it as a header (and thus not attempt to compile it), but it will list it in the generated IDE project.

**EDIT**

Based on the added information of looking for an automatic change to an existing system, I don't think that's easy. But it should still be doable. Compilers usually have a way of listing headers included by a file they compile (e.g. gcc has [`-MM`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)). You should be able to build a one-time conversion script based using this output and your favourite text-processing language.

Comment: seems like I can't just plug a `-MM` switch to my CXX flags in cmake and expect to see the output :) 
I will have to write a separate script outside of my cmake files.